# Behat - checking HTTP cache headers from several URLs

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I need to check HTTP cache headers from several URLs from a REST API responses.

I thought of using scenario outlines, but I have two situations that are creating some doubts to me.

First: some URLs need authentication and others don't. Thought of adding always authentication to background, but is not the right way.

Second: I have data features per scenario tags. In the hook before scenario, I get the data feature using the tag and setup the database. With several different URLs also doesn't feel right to have several data fixtures in the database.

What do you think is the better approach in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs needing authentication or not, is still doable with scenario outlines.

```
| endpoint                 | api_key       |
| users/1                  | 0LBX62eeA3    |
| no-auth/something        |               |
```

If the endpoint does not require authentication, avoid sending your request with an API key.

As per the second question, if I understood correctly, you would not be able to use a tag to determine which fixture to load. Again, you might be able to get around this by including that information in your example:

```
| endpoint                 | api_key       | fixture     |
| users/1                  | 0LBX62eeA3    | fixture-1   |
| no-auth/something        |               | fixture-2   |
```

I would not feel that bad by using these methods. You basically want to run the same steps through slightly different sets of data. The only thing that would not be extremely clear in this situation would be to know what's in "fixture-1" and "fixture-2", but that's probably something solvable with better naming.

Comment: Yeah, but this API needs a first request to get a token. Then in the next request if the token is in the header, the user is "authenticated". I see, put the fixture load explicitly in the gherkin...yeah is a possibility...

Comment: The request for getting a token seems like a different feature to me. You can assume you already got a token for those that require one, and seed those into your DB fixtures before running the scenario.

Comment: The problem is that the tokens are not in the DB. The token is generated and stored in a separated caching system.

Comment: If other systems are getting in the way of what you're trying to test, what you probably need is to isolate those systems entirely. This way you can swap them for a different implementation (in memory) which could allow you to provide valid API tokens on demand. If that's not possible, what you need to try to isolate is the authentication itself. Isolating authentication of the Token to a service that always accepts any request will allow you to forget about API tokens and focus on what you really want to test.